# UK Standard Visitor visa: Do I need to present bank statements if my employer is supporting my trip?

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel, proof-provenance-of-funds

Is it necessary to provide bank statements from the last six months when my employer is sending me on a trip and is paying all the costs? If providing it is not a 'must', then is it redundant and negative?

Furthermore, is it sufficient when the employer provides a simple signed letter stating that they are going to cover all expenses? Or should they provide a financial statement of some sort as well? I cannot find anything on this, GOV.UK simply says attach a letter from your employer. But is this truly enough?

Comment: See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/19560).

Comment: Which visa category are you applying for ? Why is your employer paying for you ? If you employer is bearing the cost, I am assuming it will be work related, why cann't they apply for your visa ?

Comment: @DumbCoder The title says "UK Standard Visitor visa".